# IE6 vs IE8, button vs hyperlink, CSS rendering issue

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, sliding-doors

Given the following sample  form code and CSS stylesheet

**Form**

```
<div class="Center_300 ">
 <button id="KeaneDelegate" runat="server" class="button_red2" causesvalidation="false"><span>Keane's delegate view</span></button> 
<br />
<br />
<a class="button_red2"> <span>Keane's delegate view</span></a> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.button_red2 
{
background:url('../../images/button_red_left.gif') no-repeat left top; 
display:inline;  
float:left; 
font-size:12px;  
font-weight:bold; 
line-height:16px; 
height:21px; 
padding-left:9px; 
text-decoration:none;
border-style:none; 
color:White;
 }
.button_red2  span
{   background:transparent url('../../images/button_red.gif') no-repeat top right; 
padding:3px 10px 2px 0px;
border-style:none;
display:block;
}

.Center_300 { width:300px; margin:0 auto }
```

When viewing this in  IE8's compatibility mode (IE6), the button is rendering correctly but i get 'blank' spaces to the left and right of my text.
the hyperlink renders correctly
[image]

When i switch back to native IE8 mode, the button renders correctly, as lenghty as the a hyperlink but there's a slight misalignment in the sliding door, the right part seems to be shunted 1 pixel down
[image]

If i then remove the block alignment and adjust the padding , it renders perfectly (but no longer the hyperlink)

```
.button_red2  span
{   background:transparent url('../../images/button_red.gif') no-repeat top right; 
    padding:3px 10px 3px 0px;
    border-style:none;
 }
```

[image]

But switching that back to IE6 mode makes it even more uglier

[image]

I'm trying to use a button, not a hyperlink for my forms but from the CSS style I got delivered, only the hyperlink renders perfectly between various IE versions.

Why is there that extra space in the IE6 rendering on the button? Why does it appear a pixel out of line when back to IE8 mode and how can that be sorted? Or is it not solvable?

Below the 2 gifs for the sliding doors.
[image: button_red_left]
[image]

Comment: `"IE8's compatibility mode (IE6)"` - that's not right. IE8's compatibility mode emulates IE7 *not* IE6. Can you clarify that it really is IE7 you're trying to fix, and not IE6?

Comment: i've got a VM with plain old IE6 on, the screen output there is the same (= empty spaces when using a button). We never rolled out IE7 in our enterprise.

Comment: The output here might be the same in IE6 and IE7, but you can see how I was confused when you were saying "IE8 compatibility == IE6". I'll have a look at fixing it for all of IE8/7/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is caused by the button bug in IE which is rendered too wide.
Have a look at this article: http://latrine.dgx.cz/the-stretched-buttons-problem-in-ie

Comment: Final css that works both in IE6 & IE8 : <br/> .button_red2 
{
    background:url('../../images/button_red_left.gif') no-repeat left top; 
    display:inline; 
    float:left; 
    font-size:12px;  
    font-weight:bold; 
    line-height:16px; 
    height:21px; 
    padding-left:8px; 
    padding-top:0px; 
    text-decoration:none;
    border-style:none; 
    color:White; 
    width:auto;
    overflow:visible ;}
.button_red2  span
{   background:transparent url('../../images/button_red.gif') no-repeat top right; 
    padding:3px 10px 2px 0px;
    border-style:none;
    display:block ;
}